# Python How to put "\" in a string

Tags: python, string

I wanted to find the character `\` in a string but this also happens to be the character for escaping so when i use `string1.find("\")` it doesn't work due to the backslash not letting the `"` close off the string.

If I add a trailing space, the error is fixed, however then it will not find just the backslash.

How can I put the backslash character `\` inside a string can still close it.

Comment: You mean escaping the backslash? \\

Comment: well kinda yeah, but then the string has an extra backslash which I dont want

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Could you show an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @johnhon it doesn't have extra backslash. it just displayed to you that way. try this '\\hello'[0] and '\\hello'[1]

Comment: @bman yeah thats great, I dont want to print it, i want to use the find command on it and if i do "\\" then it will try and find "\\" NOT "\". I have already tried that

Comment: whats with the downvote? what am i doing wrong? sure its a short question but i dont think that such a simple question needs a long post

Comment: Nope. `string1.find("\\")` will search `string1` for a single, literal backslash.

Comment: @johnhon can you show a bit of code? if you search for '\\' it actually only search for one backslash!

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 perhaps i am doing somthing wrong, but this is producing -1 : `str = "\afds"
print str.find("\\")`

Comment: You have to escape the backslash in `str`, too (and name it something else, or you'll have trouble accessing the built-in function `str`), e.g. `my_string = '\\afds'`.

Comment: `\a` has special meaning - so it is not treated as two chars:  \ and `a`

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 ah, didnt think of that one :P thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The way to write a string literal containing a single backslash (and nothing else) is `'\\'`.

This works in just the same way as `'\''` is a string literal containing one single quote (and nothing else).  \ + char => a single character.  What is confusing you is that if the character is not one of the recognized escaping characters (' " n \, etc) then both the backslash and the character are left in the string.

```
C:\>python Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:16:31)
[MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> '\\'
'\\'
>>> '\ '
'\\ '
>>>
```

Note how the second string is displayed with the backslash escaped.